# How to mock React Functionnal Component method?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, enzyme

I don't found a lot of jest&enzyme mock/spy example when react components are functions instead of class...

Since it looks impossible to spy on functionnal components method with "jest.spyOn" like it's possible to do with class components, is there a better or other way than passing method reference in props like my example below ?

```
  it('click on connect button', () => {
    let handleConnect = jest.fn();
    let shallowLogin = shallow(<Login handleConnect={handleConnect} />);
    //const spy = jest.spyOn(shallowLogin.instance(), 'handleConnect');
    //Impossible to spyOn like this ?
    let button = shallowLogin.find('Styled(Button)');
    button.simulate('press');
    expect(handleConnect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

I hate to do this because it's intrusive on the component code and it force the change stuff inside for the tests...

Component example :

```
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';
export default function Login(props) {
    const {register, handleSubmit, setValue} = useForm();
    const onSubmit = data => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
        if (FormValidation(data, "login")) {
            props.navigation.navigate('App');
        }
    };

    return (
    ...
                    <Button style={styles.button} rounded large onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}><Text
                        style={styles.buttonText}>{locale.t('loginScreen.CONNECT')}</Text></Button>
    ...                    
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a function component that you're having problems testing and its implementation to illustrate the issue? By definition function components have no methods so typically they take any handlers as `props` so testing like you've shown is correct.

Comment: Thx for your response azundo.. I have add a code sample of the component that I'm trying to test ( the onPress of the connect button )... Maybe that structure has a major design flaw ?

Comment: is `Button` coming from separate file? or the same?

Comment: in general, you may just add extra prop like `data-id` or something like that to make easier to distinguish components.

Comment: Ah gotcha, you're using hooks. I know less about testing hooks with enzyme - you may want to read through this thread though: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011